# finding a folder names based on list contained in .txt file

Tags: shell-script, shell, file-copy, xargs

I have a .txt file containing 150 different ID number on each line like so:

```
12345
15876
19643
12586
```

Located in the same directory as the .txt file, I have 300 folders and I want to copy only the folders whose names match those listed in the .txt file into a folder called New_Folder. Is there a simple way this can be done?

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to use `xargs`

```
xargs -a list.txt cp -t path/to/New_Folder/ -R --
```

If you wish to use a shell loop, then use `while` e.g.

```
while IFS= read -r dir; do
  cp -t path/to/New_Folder -R -- "$dir"
done < list.txt
```

Comment: I initially tried using xargs command earlier and I get the following output cp: cannot stat

Comment: It looks like it's reading each line within the txt file as one long name like this 12345/r15876/r19643

Comment: @LDG perhaps your file has DOS-style or Mac-style line endings?

Comment: Yes it does. What might be the best way to get around this issue? Sorry if this is a trivial question, I'm new to all this and have literally no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: Mac or DOS? I don't have much experience with Mac, but if the file has single CR (no LF) endings then you might be able to handle that directly using xargs `-d` or `--delimiter` e.g. `xargs -a list.txt -d $'\r' cp . . .` or `xargs -a list.txt -d '^M' cp . . . ` where `^M` is *composed* using Ctrl-V Ctrl-M. A similar `-d` argument can be added to the `read` command.

Comment: Why not `tr '\r' '\n' < list.txt | xargs cp -t /path/blabla` ?  Should work for both DOS and Mac files on a Linux-like machine. (DOS files would get extra lines which will be thrown away by xargs).

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
for dir in `cat textfile.txt`; do
    cp -a "$dir" New_Folder/
    echo Copied $dir
done
```

perhaps?

Note: if any of the directory names in textfile.txt have spaces in them, it just got harder.

Also: was there something significant about the lines in your .txt file? Were the directories on each line supposed to be treated differently from the directories on other lines?